# How to generate some keyword?

Tags: python

I try to make my own 'Word Filter'. The keywords of badword are stored in txt file. Thats work properly. But i got some issue that most people who wanna using badword replace the letter of that word. Like: Ass -> 4ss, jerk -> j3rk, etc. How can i generate more words like 4ss, j3rk and other with the rules like: a->[@, 4], e->[3], g->[6,9].

Says, this is my list of badwords:
`banana apple orange grape`. Now, according to that list, i wanna generate more word: `b@n@n@ b4n4n4 @pl3 4pl3 9r4p3 9r@p3 6r4p3 6r@p3`

How can i generate that words?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? What about creating a dictionary with chars at previous state as keys and the morphed chars as values and using that dict to generate your keyword?

Comment: your result is incorrect for banana. =>b@n@n@ b4n4n4 b@n@n@ b4n4n4 b@n@n@ b4n4n4

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev I did. I make a dictionary like `key: a, value: [@, 4]`. Read the file that contain the keyword, then put at list. Next, i looping throught the list, then loop again for each key in dictionary. Make desicion, if the value of the list contain the key in dictionary, replace with the value, then put in some list. At the end, join the result list and write to the .txt file

Comment: But that is not really what i want. What if user type `b@nan4`, there is '@' and '4'. My code does not generate that keyword(Just b@n@n@ and b4n4n4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually the easiest way to solve this IMO is recursion:

```
maps = {"a": "@", "e": "3", "g": "69"}    

def mutations(word): 
    if not word: 
        yield "" 
        return
    head, tail = word[0], word[1:] 
    for mutc in maps.get(head, "") + head: 
        yield from (mutc + rest for rest in mutations(tail))
```

This is a recursive generator that you can iterate over to get the result:

```
>>> list(mutations("pear"))
['p3@r', 'p3ar', 'pe@r', 'pear']
```

---

In the end, you won't be able to find a good technical solution to this social problem. I can think of a dozen ways to circumvent this.

Comment: I got it. This is what i looking for. Before, I can't get 'p3ar' and 'pe@r'. Thanks you @L3viathan